# How can I use a vpc security group to restrict inbound access to my Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a simply maked it with serverless endpoint for check some token. Lets say the path is "/checktoken". And want to access to it only with my Ip address, thats why connect my Lambda with VPC(2 private subnets and security group).

But problem is even I maked security group in/outbound rules as https with my IP address, I can request to the endpoint with different IP address.

I have used AWS = CloudFront + Route53 for DNS, Lambda + Api Gateway for endpoint.

I made a whitelist IP with resource policy in Api gateway which works, but its not the solution I want.

The required solution is vpc's security group should allow request only from whitelisted IP in its rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding the Lambda to a VPC **will not direct traffic to the Lambda** through your VPC.

In fact The Lambda is invoked through the Lambda API Service Endpoint, therefore inbound evaluation rules will have no effect on it at all. The purpose of a Lambda residing in a VPC is to access VPC resources.

The technical implementation is that an ENI is created in your VPC, that connects to the Lambda function in a shared AWS VPC. The Lambda is able to route out of its shared VPC to connect to resources.

> When you configure your Lambda function to connect to your own VPC, it creates an elastic network interface in your VPC and then does a cross-account attachment. These network interfaces allow network access from your Lambda functions to your private resources. These Lambda functions continue to run inside of the Lambda service’s VPC and can now only access resources over the network through your VPC.

You will need to add these IP whitelists at either the CloudFront level through the use of a [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) (using an [IPSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_IPSet.html)), or through the API Gateway as a WAF or Policy (as you mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks a lot, seem I did not understand how VPC works with lambda before. @Chris Williams

Comment: That's fine, learning is part of the journey. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: and I have one more question, this part api wants to add my lambda ip to their whitelist and response only to my ip,  If I connect my lambda function with vpc elastic IP and request does it request with elastic IP?

Comment: Right so if you do this, you will need to add routing to a NAT for the subnet the LAmbda resides in. You can give the EIP of the NAT :)

Comment: yes, will link to my new Function already done VPC (which linked to another lambda function). Thanks a lot, you save my time

Comment: No problem glad I could help ;)

Comment: Hi! @ChrisWilliams - Then why we are asked to attach a security group on Lambda when we want that to attach with VPC?

Comment: Security groups can control outbound traffic too @mygitrepo ;). They can also be used as logical references by other security groups, so your database could have an inbound rule in its security group where the source is a security group ID :)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @ChrisWilliams

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 6):

> thats why connect my Lambda with VPC(2private subnets and security group)

Placing lambda function in a VPC and giving it a security group **does not have effect** on whether the API gateway can invoke it or not.

API gateway **does not use** elastic network interface (ENI) of the lambda in the VPC to invoke it. Its done using Lambda service endpoint.

You can use WAF to control access to your CloudFront distribution:

- [Using AWS WAF to Control Access to Your Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-awswaf.html)

Comment: thanks @Marcin , probably will use API gateway resources for ip whitelist

Comment: @muzafako No problem. What do you mean that you wan to use API gateway for whitelisting? You can't specify any IPs in the API gateway. This can be done by associating WAF with API gateway.

Comment: I meant, will add allowed Ip address in "Source VPC Whitelist"
in Api gateway resource policy,

Answer (score 0):

Try Black / White listing IPAdresses:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-secure